# android: How to use SwipeRefreshLayout with SwipeListView?

Tags: android, swipe-gesture, swiperefreshlayout

The problem I am facing is the animation of swipeListView gets stuck when there is any slight downward gesture while moving from left to right.Even on refreshing the list doesn't brings the stuck view to default view. So, please help me to avoid this problem. Thank you